# Puppeteer - the browser is not opened in headless false mode

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I have was working with puppeteer with last few weeks, suddenly the headless false mode stopped opening the browser.

Library used: ***Puppeteer***

Puppeteer version: ***19.7.6***

---

Here is the code I used:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    devtools: true,
    defaultViewport: { width: 1920, height: 1080 },
    args: ['--start-maximized', '--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']
});
```

---

Any suggestion are welcomed.

Browser should open for debugging the site.